# Weakly convergent in different spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, weak-convergence

Given $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open connected and  $k\geq 0$. Let $f_n, f$ be distributions such that $$f_n \rightharpoonup f \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$$ as $n\to \infty$. Assume that $f_n \in H^k(\Omega)$ with $\sup_n\|f_n\|_{H^k(\Omega)}\leq M< \infty$.

Show the following properties

(a) $$f\in H^k(\Omega), \mathrm{~~and~~}\|f\|_{H^k(\Omega)}\leq M<\infty$$ 
(b) $$f_n \rightharpoonup f \in H^k(\Omega).$$

My attempt:

For part (a): We have the weak convergence $\int_{\Omega}(f_n-f)\psi\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ for each $\psi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$. Since $f$ is a distribution, so $\partial^{\alpha}f$ exists for any multi-index $\alpha$. We also have $\int_{\Omega}\left(\partial^{\alpha}(f_n-f)\right)\psi =(-1)^{\alpha} \int_{\Omega}(f_n-f)\partial^{\alpha}\psi$. Thus, $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ implies $\partial^{\alpha}f_n \rightharpoonup \partial^{\alpha} f$. It remains to deduce that $\partial^{\alpha}f \in L^2$. By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and weak convergence we have $$|\int_{\Omega}f\psi|\leq|\int_{\Omega}(f-f_n)\psi|+|\int_{\Omega}f_n\psi|\leq \epsilon+M\|\psi\|_2$$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Thus, $$|\int_{\Omega}f\psi|\leq M\|\psi\|_2$$ This implies that $\|f\|_2\leq M$ according to the definition of 2-norm of $f$ viewed as a functional.  But, how does one show that $\|f\|_{H^k}\leq M$?

For part (b): Given a fixed $g\in H^{k}(\Omega)$, the Cauchy-Schwarz  inequality $|\langle f_n-f, g\rangle_{H^k}| \leq \|f_n-f\|_{H^k}\|g\|_{H^k}$ does not easily imply convergence, as one needs to explain why $\|f_n-f\|_{H^k}$ approaches to zero ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I can't leave a comment yet. For (b), you already know by the uniform bound on $\lVert f_n\rVert_{H^k}$ that $f_n \rightharpoonup g$ in $H^k$ for some $g$. Then the convergence in distribution should allow you to conclude that $g=f$.

Answer (score 1):

For the part (b) you are not supposed to explain why $\|f_n−f\|_{H_k}$ approaches to zero, since it would mean you have proved the strong convergence which is not the case here. You simply need the dual to the Sobolev space, already in your "Cauchy inequality". For that you are likely to need an extension of the functions considered to use it as a kind of boundary condition. Then you use Banach-Alaoglu-Bourbaki's theorem.

Comment: Would you like to provide the details? This idea sounds abstract to me.